# LESS Mixin/Function to change a @Color HEX to RGBA to PASS into another mixin

Tags: less

I want to convert a base color in HEX (@color) to rgba and use that in a mixin like .box-shadow(x y b color);

I have seen a load of mixins to convert HEX to RGBA and set background-color, and I know I can create my own mixing for box-shadow. **But** is there a generic solution so we can use any existing mixin.

Tried/want something like this ***(doesn't work)*** :

```
/** Extend LESS functions like (lighten, darken, mix) **/
rgbaColorIn(@color, @opacity : 1){
  return rgba( red(@color), green(@color), blue(@color), @opacity );
}

// ----- or ------

/** Passing in a reference to mixin and params **/
.rgbaColorIn(@selector, @params, @color, @opacity : 1){
  @rgbaColor: rgba( red(@color), green(@color), blue(@color), @opacity );
  @selector(@params @color);
}
```

Comment: Do you mean you want to call something like `.rgbaColorIn(red, 50%)` and obtain `rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5)`?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

There is no `return` keyword in less. If you want a mixin that returns a value, then you can define a variable inside it, for example:

```
.rgbaColorIn(@color, @opacity : 1){
  @result: rgba( red(@color), green(@color), blue(@color), @opacity );
}
```

which you can access in the scope you call the mixin:

```
.section {
  .rgbaColorIn(red, 50%);
  background-color: @result;
}
```

But if you just want to generate a RGBA from a RGB color, you can use the `fade` function:

```
.section {
  @result: fade(red, 50%);
  background-color: @result;
}
```

which will render the same result in CSS:

```
.section {
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

A `.box-shadow` mixin to pass the RGB color and opacity/alpha separately could be something like this:

```
.box-shadow(@x; @y; @b; @color; @opacity) {
   box-shadow: @x @y @b fade(@color, @opacity);
   -moz-box-shadow: @x @y @b fade(@color, @opacity);
   -webkit-box-shadow: @x @y @b fade(@color, @opacity);
}
```

Which you could use in a selector like this:

```
.section {
  .box-shadow(2px; 2px; 1px; pink; 50%);
}
```

and obtain this CSS:

```
.section {
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 1px rgba(255, 192, 203, 0.5);
  -moz-box-shadow: 2px 2px 1px rgba(255, 192, 203, 0.5);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 1px rgba(255, 192, 203, 0.5);
}
```

Comment: I like SASS's approach better... you can just use the regular rgba function: `rgba($colorvariable,.4)`

Answer (score 11):

To get an rgba value (assuming you are giving it something other than 100% opacity, since LESS will just keep it as a hex value in that case), just [use the `fade()` function](http://lesscss.org/functions/#color-operations-fade). So...

**LESS**

```
@color: #ff0000;

.test {
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px fade(@color, 99%); 
}
```

**CSS Output**

```
.test {
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.99);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Good answers, I guess you also could do directly calling a box-shadow cross-browser function:

```
.toShadow(@color: red) {
  @color-rgba: rgba(red(@color), green(@color), blue(@color), .6);
  .box-shadow(~"inset 0 0 3px @{color-rgba}");
}
```

Comment: What do you think @helderdarocha